# My sprites get stuck on the edge of the screen using a C++ framework called ASGE

Tags: c++

I am using a custom game engine created by one of my lecturers.

I have 4 inputs that the user can have for a pong game. These inputs work as intended however as soon as the sprite (paddle for pong) touches either the top or the bottom they get stuck there and are unable to move. Adding an else statement saying `w_keypress = false;` doesn't work.

```
if (w_keypress)
{
   if (player_one->yPos() >= 0 && player_one->yPos() + player_one->height() <= game_height)
   {
      yspeed_player_one = -500;
      s_keypress = false;
      y_pos_player_one += yspeed_player_one * (game_time.delta.count() / 1000.f);
      player_one->yPos(y_pos_player_one);

      std::cout << "keypress w" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

EDIT: The problem can easily be fixed by setting the y value to a y value that doesn't make the sprite interfere with the top or the bottom of the screen.

e.g.

```
if (player_one-yPos() > game_height)
{
    player_one->yPos(game_height - (player_one->height() / 2)
}
else if (player_one->yPos() < 0)
{
    player_one->yPos(0 + (player_one->height() / 2)
}
```

This code detects if the player has gone off the top or the bottom of the screen and then moves the player half of its height down or up depending on which y value you are.

Comment: C++ doesn't have sprites. What framework are you using?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ASGE

Comment: First of, try using brackets `if ((player_one->yPos() >= 0) && ((player_one->yPos() + player_one->height()) <= game_height))`

Comment: @somerandomukguy Your code does what you say it does. It doesn't do anything if the paddle is off-screen, which it can easily get to. You need to clamp the value of the resulting position such that the paddle will always stay in the screen, making your enclosing `if` check redundant.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If something can't be allowed to happen, check if it's going to happen before it happens. Checking after it happens is too late more often than not..

Comment: @Rotem Please formalize that comment as an answer if you have the time.

Comment: @user4581301 No time, feel free to do so yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at

```
if (player_one->yPos() >= 0 && player_one->yPos() + player_one->height() <= game_height)
{
   yspeed_player_one = -500;
   s_keypress = false;
   y_pos_player_one += yspeed_player_one * (game_time.delta.count() / 1000.f);
   player_one->yPos(y_pos_player_one);
}
```

1. bounds check position. If in bounds,

   1. Update position by adding current velocity
2. Else

   1. Do nothing

The problem is step 1.1 is too naive. If your sprite is zipping along toward a wall at sufficient speed, it can enter or completely pass through the wall as soon as you update its position. The next test of the bounds will trap the sprite because it is out of bounds.

Eg: Sprite is at 1000. Its height is 50 and its velocity per tick is 50. The wall is at 1080.

Step 1 tests 1000 + 50 <= 1080. This is true, so step 1.1 updates the position: 1000 + 50 = 1050. The sprite now occupies 1050 to 1099 and is inside the wall.

On the next button press, Step 1 tests 1050 + 50 <= 1080. This is false, so 2.1 is executed and the sprite does not move.

The test for collision with the wall is effectively performed after the sprite's gone out of bounds [and by then it is too late](https://youtu.be/-BZxGhNdz1k?t=133).

You want a function that does something like

```
TYPE clamp_move(TYPE max_move,
               TYPE distance_to_wall)
{
    if (max_move < distance_to_wall)
    {
        max_move = distance_to_wall;
    }
    return max_move;
}
```

to prevent over shooting the bounds. Note this is pretty much `std::min`, so use `std::min`.

You wind up with

```
deltapos = std::min(yspeed_player_one * (game_time.delta.count() / 1000.f), 
                    player_one->yPos());
y_pos_player_one -= deltapos;
```

or

```
deltapos = std::min(yspeed_player_one * (game_time.delta.count() / 1000.f), 
                    game_height - (player_one->yPos() + player_one->height()));
y_pos_player_one += deltapos;
```

depending on which way the sprite is moving. Or by catching the overshoot and clamping before the next test.

```
y_pos_player_one += yspeed_player_one * (game_time.delta.count() / 1000.f);
if (y_pos_player_one <0)
{
    y_pos_player_one  = 0;
}
else if (y_pos_player_one > game_height - player_one->height())
{ 
    y_pos_player_one = game_height - player_one->height();
}
```

whichever is easier on your brain.

Comment: Could i just switch the if statements around? For example: 
```
if (player_one->yPos() etc) 
{
if (s_keypress)
   {
    yspeed_player_one = 500;
    etc
   }
}```